# Python 3.6 - Create Dropdown for selecting files in a folder

Tags: python, file, tkinter, operating-system

Simply put, I want to have a GUI using Tkinter to open a dropdown window of a filder with 30+ CSV files so that I can select a single one of them and perform further actions on them after.
Process order - Open directory -> Create Dropdown selection list -> select file -> Python selects file for further processing. So far I've been trying to mix the functions of Tkinter and os but with no luck.

```
import tkinter as tkr
import select
import sys
import os
#Basic idea of code with Os

print(' <select name="name">')
os.chdir("C:/Users/name/Desktop/folder")
for files in os.listdir("."):
    if files.endswith(".csv"):
        print('<option value="C:/users/'+files+'">'+files.replace('.csv','')+'</option>')    

#Understanding of Tkinter so far
master = tkr.Tk()
master.geometry("800x1200")
master.title("Select a File")
```

I know I need to find a way to set each CSV file as a variable and then assign them values for Tkinter to recognize and form a list from, but i don't have any clue how to do that.

Thank you.

Comment: Read up on [filedialog](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/windows.html#dialogs)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ttk.Combobox` as the dropdown selection:

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

folder = 'C:/Users/name/Desktop/folder'
filelist = [fname for fname in os.listdir(folder) if fname.endswith('.csv')]

master = tk.Tk()
master.geometry('1200x800')
master.title('Select a file')

optmenu = ttk.Combobox(master, values=filelist, state='readonly')
optmenu.pack(fill='x')

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution gave me a good direction to figure out how to continue on.